# Non-referred persistenceunit init throwing DuplicateServiceException: __FIRST_PHASE__ is already registered?

Tags: jpa, wildfly, persistence.xml, persistence-unit

I am deploying multiple war's and ear's in my Wildfly 8.1. Recently I migrated some code from hibernate to jpa in one of the jar's which is shared between a ear and a war.So this is how it goes

```
yy.ear
 -> persistence.xml(ds2,ds3,ds4)
 -> myjpa.jar
    ->persistence.xml(ds1)
xx.war
 -> myjpa.jar
    ->persistence.xml(ds1)
```

Now,yy.ear also has its persistence.xml(with references to ds2,ds3 & ds4), so does myjpa.jar(with references to ds1 only). But the error seen during deployment is saying that xx.war is trying to re-init ds4. I have checked all the source code but see no reference to ds4 in xx.war or in myjpa.jar. *So how to fix this deployment error?* Server logs below..

Also to add yy.ear gets deployed properly, but xx.war does not.

```
06:25:28,332 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ds1
06:25:28,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ds2
06:25:28,669 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ds3
06:25:28,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ds4
06:25:28,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ds2
06:25:28,679 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ds3
06:25:28,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ds4

06:25:29,352 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."xx.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."xx.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "xx.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011446: Failed to add persistence unit service for ds4
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deployPersistenceUnitPhaseOne(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:551)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.addPuService(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:264)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:191)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deploy(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.persistenceunit."xx.war#ds4".__FIRST_PHASE__ is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:158) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:235) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:767) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:317) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deployPersistenceUnitPhaseOne(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:547)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be tables with obsolete schema. Once these were dropped the deployment completed without any errors.